# How to send "defer" attribute while creating HTML via XSLT?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xslt

I need to do XML to HTML transformation via XSLT.
I have a constant like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="source.js" defer></script>
```

Oxygen Editor throws error "*Attribute name "defer" associated with an element type "script" must be followed by the ' = ' character.*" and doesn't allow to do transformation without modifying or deleting the attribute.

How can I save "defer" for transformation?
Whould it be correct to do like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="source.js" defer="1"></script>
```

?

Comment: I'd say `defer="defer"`, consistent with `readonly="readonly"` and so forth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried to assign different values to "defer" ("", "1", "defer", "$dollar") and in any case script works.
So assigning any value to "defer" works.